# How can I get from the Rotterdam cruise port to the Rotterdam Centraal train station using public transport?

Tags: public-transport, rotterdam

Can you get from the Rotterdam cruise port to the Rotterdam Centraal train station without a taxi?
I'd like to take the tram or Metro is that possible?  How much and how long would that take?

Comment: Others have already answered the question but note that if you don't have a lot of luggage (probably not your case), it's even doable by foot (maybe 40 min or so). Unlike the ferry terminals (which are deeper into the harbour), the cruise terminal is really not that far from the station/city center and there are multiple ways to reach it.

Comment: Install the [9292 public transport app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nl.negentwee) on your phone and enter your destination.

Answer (score 7):

If your cruise arrives at the Rotterdam cruise terminal, Wilhelminakade 699, 3072 AP Rotterdam, Nederland is what I get for the address, you can easily go from there by metro or by tram.

The name of the stop you need is Wilhelminakade, or Wilhelminaplein, depending on the mode of transport.

[This site](http://9292.nl/en) will help you work out the best mode of transport or combination of transport if you are based somewhere in the Netherlands.

To Rotterdam Centraal, the main railway station for the town, it is one metro ride, towards Centraal station, (might say Den Haag instead, further on the same line). There is only one line at this stop.

It is a short journey, just the fourth stop. If you own an OV Chip card for the Netherlands it will cost you € 1.26, but if you have to buy a one time ticket you pay € 3.50 for a two hour travel ticket. 
If you go by tram or bus, you only pay € 3.00 for a one hour travel ticket. (There is also a two times one hour each ticket at the Metro station for € 6.00. which might be useful for some.)

The tram to take is Tram 23 (direction centraal station) and the driver or if there the ticket collector/guard will sell you the ticket.
That takes all of 10 minutes, starting from almost the same location and the stop is about the same location as the metro stop.

If your cruise is arriving at an other place in the Rotterdam harbors it might be harder, as the harbors are extensive. The staff at the terminal you use will help you finding the best option in that case.

Answer (score 5):

[The 9292 journey planner says that there is a direct metro connection between the Rotterdam cruise port and the Centraal train station.](http://9292.nl/en/journeyadvice/rotterdam_veerhaven-rotterdam-cruise-terminal/station-rotterdam-centraal/departure/2015-04-22T1746) Walk to the Wilhelminaplein metro station, and take the D (or E) train towards Rotterdam Centraal (or Den Haag Centraal). Total cost of the journey with a OV-chipcard seem to be 1,26`EUR` or 0.83`EUR` if you are eligible for reductions. If you don't have a chipcard, [you can buy a `RET 2 uur reizen` ticket allowing you to travel 2 hours by bus, tram and metro for 3.50`EUR`](http://www.ret.nl/en/service-and-sales/tickets-and-fares.html), directly at the Wilhelminaplein metro station.

Below is a map of the metro network in Rotterdam (courtesy of [MapaMetro.com](http://mapa-metro.com/mapas/Rotterdam/mapa-metro-rotterdam.png)):

[image: Rotterdam map]

Comment: Prices only when owning an OV chip card for the Netherlands.

Answer (score -2):

***Taxi:*** around 15 euro for the 4 km, taking 15 mins.

***Metro:*** first 5 to 10 minutes walk to Wilhelminaplein metro station. From there eight minutes ride and about 2 euro per person.

So, I advise you to take taxi if you are in hurry, If you wants to save your money then, take metro.

Comment: Unless you travel at night, the taxi will take longer overall, and that is when one is waiting for you at the cruise terminal. Rotterdam local traffic can be very much blocked during normal day hours, worse in peak time.

Comment: @aitazaz, this doesn't make sense or is incomplete.  You wrote walk to Wilhelminaplein, that's fine for the Metro.  Is that where the taxi rank is?  Taxis normally have to wait at a regulated place.  Or not?  This answer needs more work to be fully complete.